# Webbrowser getelementbyname?

Tags: c#, html, input, webbrowser-control

```
<input onfocus="showInfoBox(this, "Varchar(100) Latin capital letters only (A-Z) and spaces between surnames")" onblur="hideInfoBox()" value="" name="Surname"><input>
```

I need to fill inputs via webbrowser. When i try to fill i am getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException error. How can i fill this input area?

This is my code

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("Surname")[0].SetAttribute("MySurName", "true");
```

Comment: Check me answer and tell me if helped you

Comment: not sure if I'm too late, but you could try:

   webBrowser1.Document.Window.Document.GetElementsByTagName.....

Answer (score 1):

Your code is invalid. When you are using `GetElementByTagName` you need to search by the **Tag name**. In your case is Tag Name is `input`. You can check this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also you have a typo in the name you don't have `"`. See `name=Surname"`. You can try to use `GetElementByName` method. Check this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelementcollection.getelementsbyname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). **Be aware you are missing the input type**. Search google for the didferent `input types` !

```
public HtmlElementCollection GetElemByName(string name)
{
    if (webBrowser1.Document == null)
         return null;

        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;

        return doc.All.GetElementsByName(name);                 
}
```

After that you are calling the method;

```
HtmlElementCollection col = GetElemByName("SurName");
if(col != null && col.Count > 0)
    col[0].SetAttribute("AnyAttribute", value); // be aware THERE IS NO ATTRIBUTE MySurName !!!
```

I don't know if you want to loop your elements, if you have more than one element with the same name. Also make difference between attribute and attribute value. If you want your name to became MySurName, you need this

```
col[0].SetAttribute("name", "MySurName");
```

Comment: Thank you. I think i am about the solve my problem. Just problem is with this code "col" parameter returns null value and doesnt enter if block.

Comment: that means your browser.Doucment is null or there is no elements with this name. You should debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of exception is that the function `GetElementsByTagName` founds zero element, so the collection is empty and so the exception threw when you try to access element number 1 of empty collection.

To get an element by its name like "Surname" you should use `GetElementsByName` instead of `GetElementsByTagName` which should be used for tags line 'input'.

However, no function will return a good result because the html you provided is completely malformed.

1. The 'input' tag is self-closed and should look as following: `<input .... />`. Remove unnecessary additional `'<input>'` at the end!
2. Be careful with quotation marks. In should be `onfocus="showInfoBox(this, 'Varchar(100) Latin capital letters only (A-Z) and spaces between surnames')"`; `name=Surname"` should be `name="Surname"`.
3. input must have type property (`<input type='text'` or `<input type='checkbox'`, etc)

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. It was my wrong while paste process.I tried make my question simplier and did syntacs error. Shortly i can not find smooth code that i can get input element by name.

Comment: You can change name to id and use webBrowser.Document.useGetElementById, it's even better.

Comment: Forgive me i have limited knowladge about web. Is it possible to save informations while change name to id and post it even if it is not our website? I am filling inputs on a website which not belong to me.

Comment: Most probably not. Well, you can use GetElementsByTagName("input") and then check the 'name' property. BTW, if you think my answer helps you please vote it :)

Comment: Sure it helps:) I want to know is it possible change html codes with forms applications or not because you suggested me to change name to id.

Comment: Since it's not your site, it possible to detect only by experiment.
But pay attention that you don't need to change name to id, you just can add id to element. HTML elements can have both, while id must be unique and name not.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
    Dim inp As HtmlElement
    For Each inp In wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    If inp.GetAttribute("name") = "surname" Then
    inp.SetAttribute("value", "your text")
    End If
    Next
```